# Devexpress GridControl rows savedata

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a sample GridControl and it's dataSource = List
When I run the app, I first enter a cell value, when I click enter to move to the next cell, I lost the value of the last cell;
I mean when I tape anything in any cell I lose it when I move to anther cell!! is that normal?where is my problem?

I try to bind it to a dataset, everything go OK!!

Comment: Please provide more information like view models, code-behind, XAML etc.

Comment: no It's winsform,
the problem that I didn't do any thing spacilal, I drag the control and I samply bind it to a List<Product>
when I run the app I got the column(base on product filed name)

Comment: What is `DataSource Type` a `Class`? Check whether you validate anything in property setter!